# Is there a comprehensive business listing with unique identifiers?

Tags: business

I'm doing some patent processing and was wondering if there's a master database somewhere (Bloomberg, D&B?) which uniquely identifies companies that I could map patent owners/assignees into.  The company names in the filings aren't always consistent, or may change name while keeping the same legal entity.  I'd prefer not to generate my own name/alias lookup if something already exists.

I'd prefer something from public data sources, as it seems D&B has private identifiers.  I'm looking into EDGAR, but I'm not sure that's comprehensive enough since it's based on voluntary SEC filings.

Comment: this is probably off-topic. Derwent https://clarivate.com/products/dwpi-reference-center/ has produced canonical names for patent owners and mapped patent documents to them. It is a proprietary database. They also have made their own abstracts.

Comment: I haven't used it, but Google Patents has a searchable Public Data site: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google_patents_public_datasets/google-patents-public-data

Comment: Possibly: https://www.sec.gov/rules/other/4-460list.htm

Comment: It's not uncommon for companies to wait intentionally and file assignee information later in the prosecution of a pending application, as a way to avoid tipping their hand. You'll have more success with granted patents than with applications, but it's still going to be tough depending on the company.